# Error after installing Gitlab on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, installation, gitlab, ubuntu-18.04

i want to install gitlab on ubuntu 18.04 but :-( !.

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.example.com" apt-get install gitlab-ee
```

any solution ?

- if someone already solve the same problem or something similar, thanks in advance ;-)

result  :

```
    Recipe: postgresql::enable
      * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql] action create
        - create new directory /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql
        - change mode from '' to '0755'
        - change owner from '' to 'gitlab-psql'
      * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create
        - create new directory /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data
        - change mode from '' to '0700'
        - change owner from '' to 'gitlab-psql'
      * directory[/var/log/gitlab/postgresql] action create
        - create new directory /var/log/gitlab/postgresql
        - change mode from '' to '0700'
        - change owner from '' to 'gitlab-psql'
      * link[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create (skipped due to not_if)
      * file[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile] action create
        - create new file /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile
        - update content in file /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile from none to 3b0387
        --- /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile 2019-12-13 02:51:57.452326848 +0100
        +++ /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.chef-.profile20191213-11373-1qqmckf.profile 2019-12-13 02:51:57.448326813 +0100
        @@ -1 +1,2 @@
        +PATH=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/opt/gitlab/bin:$PATH
        - change mode from '' to '0600'
        - change owner from '' to 'gitlab-psql'
      * gitlab_sysctl[kernel.shmmax] action create
        * directory[create /etc/sysctl.d for kernel.shmmax] action create (up to date)
        * file[create /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf kernel.shmmax] action create
          - create new file /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf
          - update content in file /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf from none to 75a195
          --- /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf 2019-12-13 02:51:57.464326950 +0100
          +++ /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/.chef-90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel20191213-11373-zkx5md.shmmax.conf  2019-12-13 02:51:57.464326950 +0100
          @@ -1 +1,2 @@
          +kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
        * execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax] action run
          [execute] * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
                    kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
                    net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
                    net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
                    kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
                    fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
                    fs.protected_symlinks = 1
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
                    kernel.sysrq = 176
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
                    net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
                    net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
                    net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
                    kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
                    vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
                    * Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
                    net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
                    net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ...
                    sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf": No such file or directory
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf ...
                    sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf": No such file or directory
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf ...
                    kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf ...
                    sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf": No such file or directory
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
                    * Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...

          ================================================================================
          Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax]'
          ================================================================================

          Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
          ------------------------------------
          Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
          ---- Begin output of sysctl -e --system ----
          STDOUT: * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
          kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
          net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
          net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
          kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
          fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
          fs.protected_symlinks = 1
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
          kernel.sysrq = 176
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
          net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
          net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
          net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
          kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
          vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
          * Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
          net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
          net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ...
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf ...
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf ...
          kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf ...
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
          * Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
          STDERR: sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf": No such file or directory
          sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf": No such file or directory
          sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf": No such file or directory
          ---- End output of sysctl -e --system ----
          Ran sysctl -e --system returned 255

          Resource Declaration:
          ---------------------
          # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb

           46:   execute "load sysctl conf #{new_resource.name}" do
           47:     command "sysctl -e --system"
           48:     action :nothing
           49:   end
           50: end

          Compiled Resource:
          ------------------
          # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb:46:in `block in class_from_file'

          execute("load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax") do
            action [:nothing]
            default_guard_interpreter :execute
            command "sysctl -e --system"
            backup 5
            declared_type :execute
            cookbook_name "postgresql"
            domain nil
            user nil
          end

          System Info:
          ------------
          chef_version=14.13.11
          platform=ubuntu
          platform_version=18.04
          ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
          program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
          executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


        ================================================================================
        Error executing action `create` on resource 'gitlab_sysctl[kernel.shmmax]'
        ================================================================================

        Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
        ------------------------------------
        execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb line 46) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
        ---- Begin output of sysctl -e --system ----
        STDOUT: * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
        kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
        net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
        net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
        kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
        fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
        fs.protected_symlinks = 1
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
        kernel.sysrq = 176
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
        net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
        net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
        net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
        kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
        vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
        * Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
        net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
        net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ...
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf ...
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf ...
        kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf ...
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
        * Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
        STDERR: sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf": No such file or directory
        sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf": No such file or directory
        sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf": No such file or directory
        ---- End output of sysctl -e --system ----
        Ran sysctl -e --system returned 255

        Resource Declaration:
        ---------------------
        # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/enable.rb

         67: gitlab_sysctl "kernel.shmmax" do
         68:   value node['postgresql']['shmmax']
         69: end
         70: 

        Compiled Resource:
        ------------------
        # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/enable.rb:67:in `from_file'

        gitlab_sysctl("kernel.shmmax") do
          action [:create]
          updated true
          updated_by_last_action true
          default_guard_interpreter :default
          declared_type :gitlab_sysctl
          cookbook_name "postgresql"
          recipe_name "enable"
          value 17179869184
        end

        System Info:
        ------------
        chef_version=14.13.11
        platform=ubuntu
        platform_version=18.04
        ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
        program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
        executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client

    Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
      * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action run
        - execute /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear
    Recipe: 
      * service[gitaly] action restart
        - restart service service[gitaly]
    Recipe: gitaly::enable
      * runit_service[gitaly] action hup
        - send hup to runit_service[gitaly]

    Running handlers:
    There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

    gitlab_sysctl[kernel.shmmax] (postgresql::enable line 67) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb line 46) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
    ---- Begin output of sysctl -e --system ----
    STDOUT: * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
    kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
    net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
    net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
    kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
    fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
    fs.protected_symlinks = 1
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
    kernel.sysrq = 176
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
    net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
    kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
    vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
    * Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
    net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
    net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ...
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf ...
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf ...
    kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf ...
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
    * Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
    STDERR: sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf": No such file or directory
    sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf": No such file or directory
    sysctl: cannot open "/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-net.core.somaxconn.conf": No such file or directory
    ---- End output of sysctl -e --system ----
    Ran sysctl -e --system returned 255

    Running handlers complete
    Chef Client failed. 167 resources updated in 53 seconds
    dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ee (--configure):
     installed gitlab-ee package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     gitlab-ee
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Not a programing question. Your file `/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution. (way it's work ??? xD )

I edit the file

```
sudo nano /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/package/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb
```

section

> Load the settings

to:

```
      # Load the settings right away
      #execute "load sysctl conf #{new_resource.name}" do
      #  command "sysctl -e --system"
      #  action :nothing
      #end
      execute "sysctl" do
       command "/sbin/sysctl -e -p /etc/sysctl.conf"
       action :nothing
      end

        enter code here

    end
```

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Answer (score 3):

The "`Error executing action`create`on resource 'gitlab_sysctl[kernel.shmmax`" mostly points out to `/sys` being read-only.

See for instance [`omnibus-gitlab` issue 1308](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1308)

> Set these values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on the host, and run `cat /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf | sysctl -e -p -` on the host.
>   Then run reconfigure in your lxc container again, it should detect that the kernel is already running with the necessary settings, and not make any changes.
>
> Note: the values can be found here:

```
root@gitlab:~# cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-*
kernel.sem = 250 32000 32 262
kernel.shmall = 4194304
kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
```

> I recently tried out setting up the dev environment in a `vagrant/lxc` container (debian/jessie64 box) and I had to remount `proc` filesystem in `rw` mode (using `mount -o remount rw /proc/sys`) for setting the values.

Comment: 4 years later and the problem still exists.  Luckily the fix still works as well.

Comment: It is necessary to do this in LXC containers as of today, it works perfectly. thank you!